# How to run Python from a background process?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a Python script from a (windows/c#) background process.  I'm successfully getting python.exe to run with the script file, but it's erroring out on the first line, "import pandas as pd".  The exact error I'm getting from stderr is...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predictX.py", line 1, in 
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

When I run the script from an anaconda prompt, it runs fine.  I copied the "Path" environment variable from the anaconda prompt and replicated that in my background process.  Might there be any other environment variables it's looking for?  Any other thoughts?

Thanks!!   -- Curt

Comment: does the python script run fine standalone?

Comment: pandas is on anaconda not inside the sites_packages of the python installed on your system so you need some "pip install pandas"

Comment: The script does run fine standalone in an anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You should install it in your desktop before using it.

```
$ pip install pandas
```

Then it should work fine. If not, try un-install and re-install it.

[EDIT] Anaconda is a package for python which includes more module that wasn't included in the original python installer. So the script can run in Anaconda, but not with original python runner.

Answer (score 0):

Pilot error...

Apparently there are at least two python.exe files on my computer.  I changed the path to reflect the one under the Anaconda folder and everything came right up.